# blob in data module

Tags: php, database, view, drupal-7, blob

I am using the data module in drupal 7 and i created a view which shows my table.

- But I have a blob in my table and this is filling my page with content.Is there any way that I can get the blob to display as a link and the file must be downloaded when clicked.
- Also is it possible for the data module to access tables in a different database than the default drupal database mentioned in settings.php.I added another database in the settings.php which has the required table but I am not able to adopt tables from there.(They do not show up in the orphaned tables list).Is there a place where I can change so that the data module only sees the new database and not the default database

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the first problem by doing this in the theme.inc

```
if($vars['fields'][$field] == 'content')
    {
         $field_output = "<form action=\"download.php\"      
 method=\"POST\"> 
        <input  type=\"submit\" name=\"download\" value=\"Download\"> 
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"did\" value=\"$num+1\"> 
                </form>";

    }
```

and download.php needs to have something like this

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['id'])) 
{
    $table = 'tablename';
    $download_id = $_POST['id'];
    $q="SELECT * FROM {$table} where id = $download_id";
    $link = mysqli_connect(...);
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$q);
   if($res)
   {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    header("Content-type: required type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    echo $content;
    exit;
   }
   else{
   echo "Cannot download";}

}
?>
```

I am still unable to fix the second problem.